# Let $f \in C((0;1]; \mathbb{R})$. For what $f$ every solution of $\dot{x} = x \cdot f(t), t \in (0,1]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f \in C((0;1]; \mathbb{R})$. For what $f$ every solution of $\dot{x} = x \cdot f(t), t \in (0,1]$ has this property: $lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} x(t) =0$.

Comment: Hint: $x(t) = \exp(\int f(t)\,dt)$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thank you for your hint, but this doesnt really make me any further in my solution

Comment: You can pass the limit through the exponential: $\lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)} = \exp(\lim_{x \to a} f(x) )$.